# what will be the definite integration of the following equation

Tags: calculus, integration

What will be the definite integration from 0 to inf of the cosine function

$$\int_0^\infty\cos(r)\,\mathrm dr$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\displaystyle \int _0^\infty f$?

Comment: http://goo.gl/iztj9X

Comment: You just asked this a couple of hours ago...

Answer (score 2):

This integral doesn't exist since $\displaystyle \lim_{A\to\infty}\sin A$ doesn't exist.